# Change PHP CLI's MYSQL_SOCKET configuration

Tags: php, mysql

Consider the following PHP CLI configuration directives:

```
mysql.default_socket
mysqli.default_socket
pdo_mysql.default_socket
```

What's their relation with these two:

```
MYSQL_SOCKET
MYSQLI_SOCKET
```

And how can I set the later ones? I can easily set the first three, in php.ini, to point to the correct address but it seems that it's the second two which are effective.

BTW, I'm using PHP 5.3 with php_mysql, php_mysqli and pdo_mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue just now and all I could find was this thread (and a dozen sites who ripped this thread off SO). I ended up recompiling PHP with the `--with-mysql-sock=/path/to/mysql.sock` option. It worked, but it's not going to be a real solution to anyone not able to recompile PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the CLI version is reading the correct configuration file.

```
php -c <config-file-path> <php-file>
```

Comment: It seems like my question was too brief. My problem is that there's no MYSQL_SOCKET or MYSQLI_SOCKET in the php.ini. And it's these two that are actually used, not the other ones that can be found in php.ini.

Comment: Are you using Zend? This seems related: http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=568

Comment: I am using Zend Server but the problem I mentioned is with CLI version.